# Ubuntu 15.10: Cannot expand Ubuntu partition even though I have 14GB of unallocated space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have 14GB of empty space on my drive, but when I try to expand my Ubuntu partition to occupy it, it doesn't seem to recognize the space. How can I rectify this issue and claim the free space?

[image: My GParted main screen]

[image: When I try to resize Ubuntu's partition]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partition you are trying to re-size is mounted and in use (since it's your system partition), and you cannot unmount it when it is active (also since it's your system partition).

To fix it:

- Boot from a USB or CD with a Linux live distribution (Ubuntu for example)
- Now use Gparted to re-size your partition. GParted is part of the default toolset in Ubuntu live environment.